# python : no output or only an empty list was produced

Tags: python, output, return

```
index1 = 0
singlechar = []
def SINGLE_CHAR_VAR(filename):
    firdict = vars_indents(filename)[0]
    firtup_keys = firdict.keys()
    firtup_val = firdict.values()
    for keys in firtup_keys:
        for values in firtup_val:
            index = 0
            for index in range(len(values)):
                firvallist = firtup_val[index]
                for item in firvallist:
                    if len(item[0]) == 1:
                        singlechar.append({'ERROR_TYPE': 'SINGLE_CHAR_VAR', 'LINE_NUMBER': str(keys),'COLUMN': str(item[1]),'INFO': str(item[0]),'SOURCE_LINE': str(lines[keys - 1])})
                    else:
                        continue
                return singlechar
```

this is my code but there is no output produced or when i move around the return statement an empty list was produced. i was hoping it to give me a list of dictionaries as the output.

can somebody teach me how to fix this?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function at first to get the output.

```
SINGLE_CHAR_VAR(filename)
```

**How can you expect a function to run without being called?**

Answer (score 0):

`return` != `print`. You need to do `print SINGLE_CHAR_VAR(filename)

`return` will send the value to whatever is calling that function. In this case the value/string is being returned, but you need to do something with it, hence the need for `print`. Alternatively, you can replace `return` with `print` if you want the function itself to print the output. However, in this case the value will not be passed along, and you won't be able to store it. It really just comes down to what works for you/what you want.
`

Comment: sorry for the confusion. so i have tried eg. 'print SINGLE_CHAR_VAR('naughty.py')' but it prints 'None' as its output. how can i get it to print something similar to {'ERROR_TYPE': 'SINGLE_CHAR_VAR', 'LINE_NUMBER': str(4),'COLUMN': str(89),'INFO': str('r'),'SOURCE_LINE': str('we are here')}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the **return** statement. You should **indent** the return statement right below the **outer for loop** but not below the **inner for loop**. This is shown below:

```
def SINGLE_CHAR_VAR(filename):
    firdict = vars_indents(filename)[0]
    firtup_keys = firdict.keys()
    firtup_val = firdict.values()
    for keys in firtup_keys:
        for values in firtup_val:
            index = 0
            for index in range(len(values)):
                firvallist = firtup_val[index]
                for item in firvallist:
                    if len(item[0]) == 1:
                        singlechar.append({'ERROR_TYPE': 'SINGLE_CHAR_VAR', 'LINE_NUMBER': str(keys),'COLUMN': str(item[1]),'INFO': str(item[0]),'SOURCE_LINE': str(lines[keys - 1])})
                    else:
                        continue
    return singlechar # indent of return changed
```

Comment: i have also tried changing the indentation for the return statement but it gave me [] as its output...

Comment: You should upload the file or whatever data you are working on to make it easier to fix the problem